# What does a hacker/attacker see when they try to access your Google account?

Tags: google-account, security, login

i.e. when you get the email that says "suspicious activity was detected and sign-in was blocked."
Do they see "password incorrect" or do they see "your sign in was blocked?"

Comment: Do you have enabled two-step verification?

Answer (score 3):

Just like when you enter your password incorrectly, a potential hacker sees a "Wrong Password. Try again" message.

[image: Google Sign-In Wrong Password Message]

Comment: This it's fine as a partial answer, I think. There are other cases as when the hacker found out the password, but fails to pass the 2-step verification.